# How to edit a html body served by sendFile in node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, cheerio

I try run simple html with node. I generate a page in this way:

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res){

 res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');

 });
```

In index.html is div with ID main to which I want put other page from disk depending on the URL.

for example:

http://localhost:8080 <-- here include to div home.html

http://localhost:8080/news.html <-- here include to div news.html

http://localhost:8080/contact.html <-- here include to div contact.html

etc.

I need function like PHP switch. Maybe jQuery Ajax? Page must be read before sending it to the user. I read about cheerio but I don't know how it use in my code.

Below code it work's but is it a good solution?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');
  var home = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/home.html');
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $('#main').html(home);
  res.send($.html());
});
```

Comment: please be clear. cannot understand :(

Comment: are you talking about file inclusion ?

Comment: yes, I think about file inclusion.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: With a [template](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).